# Troubleshooting dynamic dropdowns in SugarCRM 6.5

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I had asked a question here a while back about setting up database populated dropdowns for SugarCRM. I received a really good answer and, after more php studies and a dev instance running, I decided to give it a shot. The instructions I followed can be found [here](http://www.eggsurplus.com/home/content/populate-a-dropdown-from-the-database/). After I run the repair and rebuild, I would expect to see the custom field in my Fields list under the module in studio, but have not been able to find it. The module is named Makers (a1_makers as a database table). For good orders sake, there were no errors when I repaired/rebuilt after saving the files.
 Per the instructions, I first created a php file with a custom function to query the database (custom/Extension/application/Ext/Utils/getMakers.php):

```
<?php
    function getMakers() {
    static $makers = null;
    if (!$makers){
            global $db;
            $query = "SELECT id, name FROM a1_maker";
            $result = $db->query($query, false);

            $accounts = array();
            $accounts[''] = '';

            while (($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result)) !=null) {
                    $accounts[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
            }
    }
    return $makers;
 }
?>
```

Then, I set 'function' field in Vardefs to point to the function (custom/Extension/modules/Maker/Ext/Vardefs/makers_template.php):

```
<?php
     $dictionary['Maker']['fields']['list_of_makers'] = array (
          'name' => 'list_of_makers',
          'vname' => 'LBL_MKRLST'
          'function' => 'getMakers',
          'type' => 'enum',
          'len' => '100',
          'comment' => 'List of makers populated from the database',
    );
   ?>
```

Unfortunately, there are no errors and the repair/rebuild runs fine. I am just unable to see the custom field when I go into studio. Can anyone please help point out what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend checking existence of newly created field 'list_of_makers' in `cache/modules/Maker/Makervardefs.php` file. If new field definition exists in that file, try add `'studio' => 'visible'` to `custom/Extension/modules/Maker/Ext/Vardefs/makers_template.php` to get something like this:

```
<?php
     $dictionary['Maker']['fields']['list_of_makers'] = array (
          'name' => 'list_of_makers',
          'vname' => 'LBL_MKRLST'
          'function' => 'getMakers',
          'type' => 'enum',
          'studio' => 'visible'
          'len' => '100',
          'comment' => 'List of makers populated from the database',
    );
```

Try to edit your custom/modules/Maker/metadata/editviewdefs.php manually and insert field definition by hand in proper place if everything above won't work.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped clear things up. Adding the studio => visible field didn't work, but I took your advice and was able to edit the editviewdefs.php file to get it to work. I don't know why the field didn't load into Vardefs/makers_template.php, but I guess I'll just have to individually add those through each view.php file. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$dictionary['Maker']['fields']['list_of_makers'] = array (
      'name' => 'list_of_makers',
      'vname' => 'LBL_MKRLST'
      'function' => 'getMakers',
      'type' => 'enum',
      'studio' => 'visible'
      'len' => '100',
      'comment' => 'List of makers populated from the database',
      'studio' => array( 
            'listview' => true,
            'detailview' => true,
            'editview' => true
        ),
);
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation how this solves the issue?

Comment: By adding this 'studio' => array( 
            'listview' => true,
            'detailview' => true,
            'editview' => true
        ), fields will be available into studio.